# Не отображаются иконки Font Awesome 5

Tags: html, css, fontawesome

Установил себе на сайт новую версию иконочного шрифта FontAwesome.  Хотел использовать вариант "Веб-шрифты и CSS". Делаю всё по [инструкции](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css): добавляю стили в папке `css` и шрифты в папке `webfonts`, но иконки упорно не отображаются.

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<i class="fas fa-pencil"></i> 
<body>
```

Не отображаются они, кстати, и в данном сниппете, где используется CDN.

```html
<head>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<i class="fas fa-pencil"></i>
</body>
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: А путь к шрифту в  `fontawesome-all.min.css` правильно прописан?

Comment: @DmitryB., да, шрифт доступен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем как использовать иконки, проверьте их доступность. Бесплатная версия FontAwesome не поддерживает данную иконку. Вместо этого можете использовать бесплатную иконку **pencil-alt**.

```
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего вы используете бесплатную версию font awesome, тогда как иконка fa-pencil для pro версии.